# nasm How to make a text to blink?

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

This is the code for bootloader.

```
    BITS 16
start:
    mov ax, 07C0h
    add ax, 288
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096
    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax

cycle:
    mov si, message1
    call show_messages

    mov si, message2
    call show_messages

    mov si, message3
    call show_messages

    jmp $

    message1 db 13,10,"Message 1",13,10,0
    message2 db 13,10,"Message 2",13,10,0
    message3 db 13,10,"Message 3,10,0

show_messages:
    mov ah, 0Eh
repeat:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je END
    int 10h
    jmp repeat

END:
    ret
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

I need to make an message to blink and if it's possible to change the color and an message to move from right to left. How to improve this? Will this code work in virtualbox or i need to write the program on floppy disc and boot it to check?

Maybe some sugestions if its not possible to remake the code.

Comment: Assuming your video card is VGA compatible, try the wiki link for [VGA text mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode)

Answer (score 0):

I think, You need to write into the video memory. In the video memory (at 0xB800), each character on the screen (80x25 in text mode) have an attribute, whose highest bit control if the character blink or not. So if You set theses to 1, it should blinking.

```
    BITS 16
start:
    mov ax, 07C0h
    add ax, 288
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096
    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax

    mov AX,0xB800           ; set up to the video memory
    mov ES,AX
    mov CX,80 * 25 * 2 - 1  ; size of video memory
    mov BX,1

    Loop:                   ; do through on the video memory
    cmp BX,CX               ; exit if we finished
    ja Exit
    or byte [ES:BX],10000000b   ; set the highest bit to 1 (enable blinking)
    add BX,2                ; go to the next character
    jmp Loop
    Exit:

cycle:
    mov si, message1
    call show_messages

    mov si, message2
    call show_messages

    mov si, message3
    call show_messages

    jmp $

    message1 db 13,10,"Message 1",13,10,0
    message2 db 13,10,"Message 2",13,10,0
    message3 db 13,10,"Message 3",10,0

show_messages:
    mov ah, 0Eh
repeat:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je END
    int 10h
    jmp repeat

END:
    ret
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

I learned it from [www.supernovah.com](http://www.supernovah.com/Tutorials/BootSector4.php).
Important! For me, qemu and virtualbox didn't blink the text (i tried on windows), but when i tried with bochs on my android device it worked! (and when i put it on a flash disk boot sector and boot from this, it also blinked of course)